# system claimrewards not working

Tags: nodeos, cleos

I've been trying to do 
cleos --wallet-url "http://127.0.0.1:8905" system claimrewards bitgirl -p bitgirl@active

but its giving me error

Error 3050003: arisen_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: quantity exceeds available supply
pending console output:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused because the tokens you are trying to issue go beyong the max supply of the token.

So I guess what you are doing is setting the max supply of EOS to a value, and then issuing the full amount already, this won't work because claim rewards requires that the tokens issued are inflationary, and must be newly issued.

To fix this, set your max supply higher, or lower the amount of tokens that you are issuing before claiming rewards.